# How to resolve an Error on a constructor?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, awt

I don't know why it writes :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor Time(CalculAction, String) is undefine2
```

This is my code :

```
public class Build extends JFrame{

    private JTextField field1;
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox liste;
    
    public Build(){
        super();
        
        build();
    }
    
    private void build(){
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Sablier");

        menuBar.add(menu1);

        menuBar.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        

        setTitle("Sablier");
        setSize(400,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(buildContentPane());
    }

    private JPanel buildContentPane(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        field1 = new JTextField();
        field1.setColumns(10);
        
        panel.add(field1);

        JButton bouton = new JButton(new CalculAction(this, "Go"));
        
        panel.add(bouton);
        
        label = new JLabel("Il reste : " + "la variable" + " sec");
        
        panel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        panel.add(label); 

        return panel;
    }

    public JTextField getField1(){
        return field1;
    }
    
    public JLabel getLabel(){
        return label;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CalculAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Build fenetre;
    
    public CalculAction(Build fenetre, String texte){
        super(texte);
        
        this.fenetre = fenetre;
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        String nombre1String = fenetre.getField1().getText();
        double nombre1 = Double.parseDouble(nombre1String);

        if (nombre1 >= 6000){
            fenetre.getLabel().setText("Error://incorect data");
        }
        else if (nombre1 <= 0){
            fenetre.getLabel().setText("Error://incorect data");
        }
        else{

            Time Time = new Time(this, "Time");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Time {
    private Build fenetre;

    public Time(Build fenetre, String texte){
        super(texte);
        
        this.fenetre = fenetre;
    }
    public Time(){
        String nombre1String = fenetre.getField1().getText();
        double nombre1 = Double.parseDouble(nombre1String);
        
        double Time = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= nombre1; i++){
            fenetre.getLabel().setText("Le temps passé est " +  Time + " sec");
            Time++;
            if (Time == nombre1){   
                fenetre.getLabel().setText("ALERTE!");
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            }
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing an hourclock.

Comment: You don't declare `Time` as extending another class, so what is `super(texte);` supposed to do inside a `Time` constructor?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong Time class, not the one you expect. For example, you think you're instantiating the class Time you implemented, and instead (maybe) you are using java.sql.Time. 
Can you please add into the code above also all the "import" statements?

Comment: Also `new Time(this, "Time");` where `this` is a `CalculAction` is trying to call a `Time` constructor that does not exist.

Comment: *"I am doing an hourclock."* Please [edit] the question to add that information. It will be more visible than in comments.

Comment: Did you put all your classes in the same package?

Comment: That's just one problem, because you dont extend any class, so you cannot invoke any constructor of superclass

Comment: and with wich extends. AbstractAction?

Comment: the Error is   at CalculAction.actionPerformed(CalculAction.java:29)

Comment: *"Please anwser"* Don't add things like that in questions, and certainly not in titles. It will not elicit more or better responses - it is just noise. Think about it. This is a Q&A site. You asked a question, why would people even see it if they're not interested in offering an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achive, but regarding your compilation issue, I notice two errors in your code:

1. Remove the call `super(texte)` from `Time` constructor, as the class doesn't extend any other class, so you cannot invoke any constructor of superclass.
2. The constructor `Time(Build, String)` accept a `Build` instance as first parameter, so you cannot pass `this` when instantiate Time variable inside `CalculAction`, because it would refer to the instance of CalculAction class, but you have to pass the instance member `fenetre`, in this way:

   Time Time = new Time(fenetre, "Time");

Comment: I tried myself and the code compiles in this way.